# IE AntiForgeryToken Limit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I had a bug in a web page where IE wouldn't load it. It appears to be because I had multiple forms with anti-forgery tokens on the page..

I can replicate it by simply putting the code below into an MVC page.

This only affects IE, Firefox and Chrome both load the page.

I have managed to work around the issue by re-designing the page but would like to know what the limitation is in IE.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 242; i++)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="text-input-@i" name="text-input-@i" value="" placeholder="text @i" />
            <input type="button" id="button-@i" name="button-@i" value="Click Me!"  />
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <hr />
        </div>
    }
}
```